# JFXDialog extra space around the content

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

As you can see from the picture after I set my content Node there is all this non red space around it. How can I remove it? I've been messing with for an hour with no luck.
Library is called **JFoenix**.
[image: JFXDialog extra space example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
 dialog.getContent().setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

EDIT:
Make sure to do this after the actual content has been set.